# How can add text to the center of a D3 sunburst diagram

Tags: d3.js, sunburst-diagram

I am using the [zoomable sunburst example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4348373) but I am struggling trying to add a text to the center of the diagram and still make it zoomable.
The idea is that the text in the center will change when I click on a certain arc indicating its length. It seems that the properties of the mouseclick and mouseover dissapear.
This is what I have tried:

```
path.append("svg:text")
        .on("click",click)
        .style("font-size","4em")
        .style("font-weight","bold")
        .text(function(d) { return count_function(data); });
```

Can someone help me understand how to display the text in th center of the chart without losing the click functionality?

Maybe an easier approach would be to select the "g" that represents the circular centre and add text to it once the chart was been displayed. I have tried this but I am unable to successfylly select just this element (sorry I am new to D3), so back to square one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to insert a `text` element inside a `path` element. Try something like this:

```
svg.select("g").append("svg:text")
    .on("click",click)
    .style("font-size","4em")
    .style("font-weight","bold")
    .text(function(d) { return count_function(data); });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Richard! However it is still not working. I can see the text for a second as it gets hidden by the fill of the first circle.

Comment: Just a guess, but is the text being declared first? There's no z-index in SVG so the order the elements are appended affects which ones can be seen.

Comment: Yes, the text is fine. I have managed to make it visible if I follow your advise and append the text to the "g" element after the svg is created. However, when I do the transition I lose the text.

Comment: Could you put a working copy with the transition problem on JSFiddle? It's hard for me to say what the problem is without seeing it

Comment: The code is from this example: [link](http://bl.ocks.org/adewes/4710330/94a7c0aeb6f09d681dbfdd0e5150578e4935c6ae). The transitions are in function animate()

Comment: Putting your work on JSFiddle makes it easier for others to debug than reading static code that your problematic code is based on. I answered your original question. These subsequent questions are starting to feel a bit like I'm just doing your work for you, so I'm going to step out now. Suggest you examine what's being created in the DOM using your browser's DOM inspector and investigate further, or post another question.